Android notification permission localization (or change language)
enter image description here
As you see my phone language is Turkish but permission text shows in English. When I change phone language just 'Cancel' text changed with 'İptal'.
I want the permission text to change depending on the language of the phone.
Thank you in advance for your answer..

Can you share the code related to showing this notification?

// OneSignal.Debug.setLogLevel(LogLevel.Verbose);
OneSignal.initialize('myAppId');
OneSignal.User.setLanguage('tr');
await OneSignal.Notifications.requestPermission(true);
OneSignal.login((response.data?.id ?? 0).toString());
OneSignal.User.addTags({
//my tags
});
#it is react-native

same problem also in flutter

@RamazanAltun please edit your question and add the code form where it's calling, if func. than also share that code as well for clear picture of you problem.
